# phpunit: Best practice for testing static method

Tags: php, oop, testing, phpunit

PHPUnit 3.7

Since three weeks I am testing with PHPUnit and did a lot of easy Unittest (also with dataPrividers) - I like it.

The last days I am struggling to mock objects - no success :-(

I want to test the following static function: `Tools::getValue();`. It gets some object and the name of an attribute of that object, does some things, and gives the value of the attribute back. I am using such functions quite often.

Is it to test it with `getMock`? I wasn't successful till now and reading didn't help.

```
# Tools.php
<?php
  class User
  {
     public $lastname, $city;
  }

  class Tools
  {
     /**
      * Gets an attribute of my_object -> trimms the spaces and gives it back in uppercase.
      * This work for any object/attribute.
      * 
      * @param type $my_object 
      * @param string $attribute is a name of an attribute of my_object
      * @return string 
      */
      public static function getValue($my_object, $attribute)
      {
         $value = $my_object->$attribute;
         $ret = strtoupper(trim($value));
         return $ret;
       }
}
```

And it works:

```
# use.php
<?php
$teacher = new User();
$teacher->lastname = "Kennwood";
$teacher->city = "New York";
echo Tools::getValue($teacher, "lastname");

// Result KENNWOOD
```

And testing also works - but I think my way is not OK in this case:

```
# ToolsTest.php
<?php
class ToolsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testGetValue()
    {
        $teacher = new User();
        $teacher->lastname = "Kennwood";
        $teacher->city = "New York";

        $actual = Tools::getValue($teacher, "lastname");
        $this->assertEquals("KENNWOOD", $actual);           
    }
}
```

It works, but the bad thing is this test depends on the class `User` or an other class I use to build the needed object for the test - and I think that is no good testing design.

How could I mock an object for this case or what is good testing practice in this case?

Comment: You say that you started testing with PHPUnit three weeks ago. Why did you choose a version of PHPUnit that is unsupported for years?

Comment: On my Linux-Distribution I have php 5.5.9 and I am using composer to install phpunit, selenium, dbunit, ... composer showed conflicts till I choose phpunit 3.7.  I have to go further with my project and fear time-problems when I Upgrade now my whole Developing-IDE now. No good idea?

Comment: PHPUnit 4.8 is supported on PHP 5.3, PHP 5.4, PHP 5.5, and PHP 5.6.

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled composer, changed configuration ... and this time composer installed phpunit 4.8 :-) Now please back to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't find an other solution and though I think the way I did the test is not really good - maybe it's the best workaround.

On PHPUnit-Documentation I found:

> Limitation: final, private, and static methods
>
> Please note that final, private and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked

I am not quite shure but to me it sounds as if testing static methods with dependencies to objects is not possible with with PHPUnit.